# Entity Framework - Multiple FK references to same table, different instances

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I am trying to create a relation between two tables, `Category` and `CategoryCombination`.

`Category` can either be a plain category, or it can be a combination of two other categories.

`CategoryCombination` is a relationship table. It has the `Id` of the new category that is created, and the id of one of the sub-categories that it is a combination of. If a category is created, which is a combination of two other categories, it will create two rows in the `CategoryCombination` table.

I have created a simplified example where there are categories of genre:

`CategoryCombination` table example:

| new_category_id | sub_category_id |
| --- | --- |
| 15 | 3 |
| 15 | 6 |
| 18 | 8 |
| 18 | 6 |

`Category` table example:

| category_id | name | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Action | —- |
| 4 | Comedy | —- |
| 6 | Thriller | —- |
| 8 | Romance | —- |
| 15 | Thrilling Action | —- |
| 18 | Thrilling Romance | —- |

Code:

```
[Table("CATEGORY_COMBINATION")]
public class CategoryCombinationEntity
{
    [Column("NEW_CATEGORY_ID")]
    [Required]
    public int NewCategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(NewCategoryId))]
    public CategoryEntity NewCategory { get; set; }

    [Column("DEL_KONTROLLTYPE_ID")]
    [Required]
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(SubCategoryId))]
    public CategoryEntity SubCategory { get; set; }
}

[Table("CATEGORY")]
public class CategoryEntity
{
    [Column("CATEGORY_ID")]
    [Required]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Column("Name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CategoryCombinationEntity> SubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

**Problem**: in the `CategoryCombination` table, there are two foreign keys referencing the same table (although different instances), which causes me some issues when I am trying to configure it in the `OnModelCreating` method.

I tried this code:

```
public static void OnModelCreating_Category(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<CategoryEntity>()
        .HasMany(k => k.SubCategories)
        .WithOne(k => k.NewCategory)
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.NewCategoryId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<CategoryEntity>()
        .HasMany(k => k.SubCategories)
        .WithOne(k => k.SubCategory)
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.SubCategoryId);
}
```

But I got the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException. Cannot create a relationship between CategoryEntity.Subcategories' and 'CategoryCombinationEntity.SubCategory' because a relationship already exists between 'CategoryEntity.SubCategories' and 'CategoryCombinationEntity.NewCategory'. Navigations can only participate in a single relationship.

I also tried this:

```
public static void OnModelCreating_CategoryCombinationEntity(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<CategoryCombinationEntity>()
                .HasKey(k => new
                             {
                                 k.newCategoryId,
                                 k.subCategoryId
                             });

    modelBuilder.Entity<CategoryCombination>()
                .HasOne(k => k.NewCategory)
                .WithMany(k => k.SubCategories)
                .HasForeignKey(k => k.NewCategoryId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<CategoryCombination>()
                .HasOne(k => k.SubCategory)
                .WithMany(k => k.SubCategories)
                .HasForeignKey(k => k.SubCategoryId);
}
```

I got the same type of `System.InvalidOperationException` for this code.

How can I solve this?

---

It should also be noted that I have found other questions that are similar ([Multiple foreign keys on the same table. How to redesign my model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66521535/multiple-foreign-keys-on-the-same-table-how-to-redesign-my-model)). However, here the suggested solutions are to create two different collections, which will not work in my case.

Comment: Did you try configuring `CategoryCombination` instead?

Comment: I did, let me update the question!

Comment: I thought you had 2 different collections (sorry for misreading),  As mentioned in the linked question you can not have 2 two relationships pointing to the same collection.

Comment: Okey, but is there an alternative?

Comment: Well, the only alternative is to have two collections which you don't want.

Comment: I understand. The alternative: 
public ICollection<CategoryCombinationEntity> StandaloneCategories { get; set; } ICollection<CategoryCombinationEntity> CombinedCategories { get; set; } } 

Will unfortunatly not make sense, since a Category wont ever have a list of standalone categories, it will only have a list of sub_categories if a category is a categorycombination. 

So I will have to figure something else out.
Thank you very much for your help anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you could try
    modelBuilder.Entity<CategoryCombinationEntity>()
        .HasOne(k => k.NewCategory)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.NewCategoryId);